# Changing just 1 value in a view frame

Tags: ios, view, frame, cgrect

I am somewhat new to iOS and to change the width or height of a view I am using the following code:

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,
                        view.frame.origin.y,
                        view.frame.size.width,
                        newHeight);
```

This feels wrong because I am copying all of the old values into a new rect just to change a single value, but I can't just do:

```
view.frame.size.height = newHeight;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you cant assign individual properties of CGRect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign the values directly. You have to create a variable for it:

```
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.size.height = newHeight;
view.frame = frame;    // or [view setFrame:frame];
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way which helps you keep the frame variable in a different scope:

```
view.frame = ({
    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    frame.size.height = newHeight;
    frame;
});
```